# Controller's property is not showing up on template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a template that serves as a user registration page. It has e-mail, password, password confirmation, first and last name. And then, there is a button that it supposed to call an action defined int the controller. The handlebars template looks something like this.

```
<div class="well">

    <form role="form">
        <div class='form-group'>
            {{input type='email' class='form-control' placeholder='E-Mail' value=email}}
        </div>

        <div class='form-group'>
            {{input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='First Name' value=password}}
        </div>

        <div class='form-group'>
            {{input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Last Name' value=password}}
        </div>

        <div class='form-group'>
            {{input type='password' class='form-control' placeholder='Password' value=password}}
        </div>

        <div class='form-group'>
            {{input type='password' class='form-control' placeholder='Password Confirmation' value=passwordConfirmation}}
        </div>

        <button {{action 'signUp'}} class='btn btn-lg btn-default'>Sign Up</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Now, I want to render an error on that same page whenever there is a validation error (e.g. missing email). To do this, I have basic validation rules in my action and, in addition to that, defined another property called `signUpError`. My controller looks something like this.

```
Postr.SignUpController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        signUp: function(){

            var email = this.get('email');
            var password = this.get('password');
            var passwordConfirmation = this.get('passwordConfirmation');
            var firstName = this.get('firstName');
            var lastName = this.get('lastName');

            console.log(email);

            if(!email || !password || !passwordConfirmation || !firstName || !lastName){
                this.set('signUpError ', 'One or more field is missing!');
            }
            if(password !== passwordConfirmation){
                this.set('signUpError ', 'Password does not match!');
            }

            //console.log(this.get('signUpError'));
        }
    },

    signUpError: ''
});
```

And, on top of the form, I add a new HTML element to render the error.

```
{{#if signUpError}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{signUpError}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

Problem is that... I cannot get the `signUpError` to show up :| any ideas?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but in your `this.set('signupError ') you have a space at the end. Maybe that will fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your this.set('signupError ') has a space, so you aren't actually setting the property correctly.

I've recreated the issue in a jsbin, and without the space the issue works fine.

`this.set('signUpError', 'Password does not match!');`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hicefefibe/1/

Comment: HOLY MACARONI THANK YOU!